# TDD test class for ViewModel class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, moq

I am currently writing my first TDD application. The project is in Xamarin.Forms and tested in xUnit. I am also using Autofac and Moq.

> The first class below is testing second class (VM). The VM is:
>
> - `LoadGroups` method is populating collection of group names (strings),
> - `LoadFromFile` method is loading from CSV file string with data and creates collection of objects,
> - `PopulateDb` method takes collection of objects and seeds DB with them.

I wonder if maybe more experienced developers will have any comments or suggestions regarding the code or architecture, before I will continue with next View Models, to avoid corrections.

[Test class](https://github.com/przemyslawbak/Flashcards/blob/master/Flascards.UnitTests/ViewModels/MainPageViewModelTests.cs):

```
public class MainPageViewModelTests
    {
        List<Phrase> phrases;
        private MainPageViewModel _viewModel;
        private Mock<IPhraseEditViewModel> _phraseEditViewModelMock;
        private Mock<IMainDataProvider> _mainDataProviderMock;
        public MainPageViewModelTests()
        {
            //instances
            phrases = new List<Phrase>
            {
                new Phrase { Category = "newCat1", Definition = "newDef1", Group = "newGr1", Learned = false, Name = "newName1", Priority = "newPrio1", Id = 7 }
            };
            _phraseEditViewModelMock = new Mock<IPhraseEditViewModel>();
            _mainDataProviderMock = new Mock<IMainDataProvider>();

            //setup
            _mainDataProviderMock.Setup(dp => dp.GetGroups())
                .Returns(new List<string>
                {
          "Group #1",
          "Group #2",
          "Group #3"
             });
            _mainDataProviderMock.Setup(dp => dp.PickUpFile())
                .ReturnsAsync("goodData.csv");
            _mainDataProviderMock.Setup(dp => dp.GetStreamFromCSV("goodData.csv"))
                 .Returns("Name|Definition|Category|Group|Priority\nname1 |def1|cat1|gr1|prio1\nname2 |def2|cat2|gr2|prio2");
            _mainDataProviderMock.Setup(dp => dp.GetStreamFromCSV("emptyData.csv"))
                .Returns("");

            //VM instance
            _viewModel = new MainPageViewModel(_mainDataProviderMock.Object, CreatePhraseEditViewModel);
        }

        private IPhraseEditViewModel CreatePhraseEditViewModel() //method for creating PhraseEditVM
        {
            var phraseEditViewModelMock = new Mock<IPhraseEditViewModel>();
            phraseEditViewModelMock.Setup(vm => vm.LoadPhrase(It.IsAny<int>()))
              .Callback<int?>(phraseId =>
              {
                  phraseEditViewModelMock.Setup(vm => vm.Phrase)
            .Returns(new Phrase());
              });
            _phraseEditViewModelMock = phraseEditViewModelMock; //field = var(!!)
            return phraseEditViewModelMock.Object;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void LoadGroups_ShouldLoadOnce_True()
        {
            _viewModel.LoadGroups(); //loads groups twice
            _viewModel.LoadGroups();

            Assert.Equal(3, _viewModel.Groups.Count); //counts how many groups are loaded
        }
        [Fact]
        public void LoadGroups_ShouldLoad_True()
        {
            _viewModel.LoadGroups(); //loads collection of groups (from setup)
            Assert.Equal(3, _viewModel.Groups.Count); //counts groups
            var phrase = _viewModel.Groups[0];
            Assert.NotNull(phrase);
            Assert.Equal("Group #1", phrase); //compares group name
        }
        [Fact]
        public void AddPhrase_ShouldBeExecuted_True()
        {
            _viewModel.PhraseEdit = false; //set up PhraseEdit prop
            _viewModel.AddPhraseCommand.Execute(null); // executes command
            Assert.True(_viewModel.PhraseEdit); //verifies PhraseEdit prop
            _phraseEditViewModelMock.Verify(vm => vm.LoadPhrase(null), Times.Once); //counts loaded phrases
        }
        [Fact]
        public void LoadFromFile_ShouldConvertReturnedCorrectFormatString_ReturnsPhraseList()
        {
            _viewModel.LoadFromFile("goodData.csv"); //loads phrases from the file
            Assert.Equal(2, _viewModel.LoadedPhrases.Count); //counts loaded phrases from the file
            var phrase = _viewModel.LoadedPhrases[0];
            Assert.NotNull(phrase); //checks if phrase is not null, below compares props
            Assert.Equal("name1", phrase.Name);
            Assert.Equal("def1", phrase.Definition);
            Assert.Equal("cat1", phrase.Category);
            Assert.Equal("gr1", phrase.Group);
            Assert.Equal("prio1", phrase.Priority);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void PopulateDb_ShouldSeedDbWithPhrases_CallsDpSavePhrase()
        {
            _viewModel.LoadedPhrases = phrases; //populates collection
            _viewModel.PopulateDb(_viewModel.LoadedPhrases); //populates Db with phase list - 1 item
            _mainDataProviderMock.Verify(dp => dp.SavePhrase(It.IsAny<Phrase>()), Times.Once); //counts saved phrases
        }
        [Fact]
        public void LoadFile_ShouldBeExecuted_CallsOnLoadFileExecute()
        {
            _viewModel.LoadFile.Execute(null); //execute command
            Assert.Equal(2, _viewModel.LoadedPhrases.Count()); //counts loaded phrases from the file
            Assert.Equal(3, _viewModel.Groups.Count); //counts loaded groups
            _mainDataProviderMock.Verify(dp => dp.SavePhrase(It.IsAny<Phrase>()), Times.AtLeast(2)); //counts saved phrases
        }
        [Fact]
        public void PopulateDb_ShouldSeedDbOnce_True()
        {
            _viewModel.LoadedPhrases = phrases; //populates collection
            _viewModel.PopulateDb(_viewModel.LoadedPhrases); //seeds Db twice
            _viewModel.PopulateDb(_viewModel.LoadedPhrases);
            _mainDataProviderMock.Verify(dp => dp.SavePhrase(It.IsAny<Phrase>()), Times.Once); //should seed only once
        }
        [Fact]
        public void LoadFromFile_WithFilePathParameterIsNull_ReturnsEmptyCollection()
        {
            List<Phrase> expected = new List<Phrase>();
            expected.Clear(); //expectations
            List<Phrase> method = _viewModel.LoadFromFile("");//loads phrases from the file with empty path parameter
            _viewModel.LoadFromFile(""); //loads phrases from the file with empty path string
            Assert.Empty(_viewModel.LoadedPhrases); // check if LoadedPhrases is empty
            Assert.Equal(expected, method); //compare expectations with method returns
        }
        [Fact]
        public void PopulateDb_GetsEmptyCollectionParameter_DoesNothing()
        {
            _viewModel.LoadedPhrases.Clear(); //collection is empty
            _viewModel.PopulateDb(_viewModel.LoadedPhrases); //PopulateDb with empty collection
            _mainDataProviderMock.Verify(dp => dp.SavePhrase(It.IsAny<Phrase>()), Times.Never); //with empty collection SavePhrase runs never
        }
        [Fact]
        public void LoadFromFile_GetsPathToEmptyFile_ReturnsEmptyCollection()
        {
            List<Phrase> expected = new List<Phrase>();
            expected.Clear(); //expectations
            List<Phrase> method = _viewModel.LoadFromFile("emptyData.csv"); //loads phrases from the file with empty content
            Assert.Empty(_viewModel.LoadedPhrases); // check if LoadedPhrases is empty
            Assert.Equal(expected, method); //compare expectations with method returns
        }

        //TODO:
        //zły format pliku
        //brak | w pliku
    }
```

[Tested View Model class](https://github.com/przemyslawbak/Flashcards/blob/master/Flascards.UnitTests/ViewModels/MainPageViewModelTests.cs):

```
public interface IMainPageViewModel
    {
        void LoadGroups();
    }
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMainPageViewModel
    {
        List<Phrase> oldPhrases = new List<Phrase>(); //verification for PopulateDb method;
        private Func<IPhraseEditViewModel> _phraseEditVmCreator;
        private IMainDataProvider _dataProvider;
        public string FileLocation { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Groups { get; set; }
        public List<Phrase> LoadedPhrases { get; set; }
        public bool PhraseEdit { get; set; }
        public IPhraseEditViewModel SelectedPhraseEditViewModel { get; set; }
        public MainPageViewModel(IMainDataProvider dataProvider,
            Func<IPhraseEditViewModel> phraseditVmCreator) //ctor
        {
            _dataProvider = dataProvider;
            _phraseEditVmCreator = phraseditVmCreator;
            Groups = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            LoadedPhrases = new List<Phrase>();
            //commands tests
            AddPhraseCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnNewPhraseExecute);
            LoadFile = new DelegateCommand(OnLoadFileExecute);
        }

        public ICommand AddPhraseCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand LoadFile { get; private set; }

        private void OnNewPhraseExecute(object obj)
        {
            SelectedPhraseEditViewModel = CreateAndLoadPhraseEditViewModel(null);
        }

        private IPhraseEditViewModel CreateAndLoadPhraseEditViewModel(int? phraseId)
        {
            //Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new PhraseEditPage());
            var phraseEditVm = _phraseEditVmCreator();
            PhraseEdit = true;
            phraseEditVm.LoadPhrase(phraseId);
            return phraseEditVm;
        }
        private async void OnLoadFileExecute(object obj)
        {
            LoadedPhrases.Clear();
            FileLocation = await _dataProvider.PickUpFile();
            LoadedPhrases = LoadFromFile(FileLocation);
            PopulateDb(LoadedPhrases);
            LoadGroups();
        }
        public void LoadGroups() //loads group list from the DB
        {
            Groups.Clear();
            foreach (var group in _dataProvider.GetGroups())
            {
                Groups.Add(group);
            }
        }
        public List<Phrase> LoadFromFile(string filePath)
        {
            if (filePath != "")
            {
                string stream = "";
                LoadedPhrases.Clear();
                stream = _dataProvider.GetStreamFromCSV(filePath);
                Dictionary<string, int> myPhraseMap = new Dictionary<string, int>(); //exception for wrong format
                var sr = new StringReader(stream);
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(sr, true, '|'))
                {
                    int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
                    string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        myPhraseMap[headers[i]] = i;
                    }
                    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
                    {
                        Phrase phrase = new Phrase
                        {
                            Name = csv[myPhraseMap["Name"]],
                            Definition = csv[myPhraseMap["Definition"]],
                            Category = csv[myPhraseMap["Category"]],
                            Group = csv[myPhraseMap["Group"]],
                            Priority = csv[myPhraseMap["Priority"]],
                            Learned = false
                        };
                        LoadedPhrases.Add(phrase);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LoadedPhrases.Clear();
            }
            return LoadedPhrases;
        }
        public void PopulateDb(List<Phrase> phrases)
        {
            if (oldPhrases != phrases) //populates only if collection is new
            {
                foreach (var item in phrases)
                {
                    _dataProvider.SavePhrase(item);
                }
                oldPhrases = phrases;
            }
        }
    }
```

[GitHub repository of the project](https://github.com/przemyslawbak/Flashcards/tree/master/Flashcards/Flashcards)

Answer (score 2):

### `MainPageViewModel`

You provide an interface with a single method:

> ```
> public interface IMainPageViewModel
> {
>     void LoadGroups();
> }
> ```

Yet, the implementation provides a rich set of public members:

> ```
> public string FileLocation { get; set; }
> public ObservableCollection<string> Groups { get; set; }
> public List<Phrase> LoadedPhrases { get; set; }
> public bool PhraseEdit { get; set; }
> public IPhraseEditViewModel SelectedPhraseEditViewModel { get; set; }
> // and so on ..
> ```

I'm not a fan of this, because this means there is a clear difference between the public API of the implementation and its interface. Perhaps some of these members are specific to the implementation, but surely `ObservableCollection<string> Groups { get; }` should be part of the interface. Or `IReadOnlyCollection<string>` if only readonly mode is allowed. I guess the former would be required for your use cases.

You are mixing naming conventions lowercase `oldPhrases` vs _lowercase `_dataProvider`. Stick to a single standard.

Be careful designing mutable properties `ObservableCollection<string> Groups { get; set; }`. It allows consumers to bypass the interface method `LoadGroups()` to set `Groups`. This might be considered a breach of encapsulation. Also, a null reference can easily occur:

> ```
> public void LoadGroups()
> {
>     Groups.Clear();  // possible NullReferenceException
>     foreach (var group in _dataProvider.GetGroups())
>     {
>         Groups.Add(group);
>     }
> }
> ```

[There is alot to say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167307/how-to-use-async-method-in-delegatecommand) about `DelegateCommand` using an `async void` action like `OnLoadFileExecute`. I would opt to use a (custom) `AsyncDelegateCommand` that takes a `Task` instead, optionally with a nested `CancelCommand`.

Method `LoadFromFile` mixes IO, mapping and changing instance state. This might be a bit too much for a single method. Consider splitting this up in classes/methods that each have their own responsibility. Readability could also be improved by inverting the if-statement with an early exit to avoid deep nested statements.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
{
    LoadedPhrases.Clear(); // assuming the instance can never be null
    Clear();
    return;
}

// remaining method body ..
```

If `filePath` is null, you probably get an annoying exception, so prefer `string.IsNullOrEmpty` over `!= ""`.

Use `var` when the type is obvious to write more compact and clean code: `Phrase phrase = new Phrase(..` -> `var phrase = new Phrase(..`.

`PopulateDb` doesn't seem right. You check on reference equality of the collections. But what if a different stores the same or some of the same items? You would save certain items more than once: `_dataProvider.SavePhrase(item);` -> if the item is also contained in `oldPhrases`. You have many unit tests, but in TDD you should also find these edge cases I would expect.

> ```
> if (oldPhrases != phrases) //populates only if collection is new
> ```

### `MainPageViewModelTests`

You have written [white-box tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing), and you've done it the correct way. The only class you instantiate is the class under test:

> ```
> _viewModel = new MainPageViewModel(..
> ```

While other dependencies get mocked:

> ```
> _phraseEditViewModelMock = new Mock<IPhraseEditViewModel>();
> _mainDataProviderMock = new Mock<IMainDataProvider>();
> ```

Allowing for tests against the dependencies without needing to worry about any of their possible implementations:

> ```
> _phraseEditViewModelMock.Verify(vm => vm.LoadPhrase(null), Times.Once);
> ```

However, you did not write any significant number of [black-box tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing): tests where you check output given some input. By writing more of these tests for edge cases in particular, you would have found a couple of `NullReferenceException` errors.